# jQuery ajax with httppost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a jQuery Ajax request to the controller method of ASP.NET MVC Core.

**jQuery Code**

```
var mydata = JSON.stringify({
        "ID": $('#ID').val(),
        "text": $.trim($("#txt").val())
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postdata',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        data: mydata,
        cache: false,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("/postdata")]
    public IActionResult postdata([FromBody] Model model)
    {           
        //process model
        return Json(model);
    }
```

If the user is authenticated then everything works fine however if the user is not authenticated then
jQuery Ajax requests throws "Bad Request"

I am looking to ajax request should execute with valid tokens in any case of user authenticated or not.

Comment: it's work correct for me! can you share request inspect or html form  in view?

Answer (score 1):

> If no **method** attribute is added to form, then I can indeed
> reproduce your error.

I think this is related to your **html with form in the view**.

Since you added the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute to the action, you need to pass the **AntiForgery token** together when you pass the post.

You did add this in the `headers`, but if you use ***F12 to debug*** this sentence: `$('input[name ="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()` value, you will find that it is *undefined*, which is the cause of the problem.

To solve this problem, please make sure that the **`method="post"`** attribute is added to the `form` where the button that triggered the js event is located.

Here is my demo:

```
 <form method="post">
        <input id="ID" type="text" />
        <input id="txt" type="text" />
        <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>

 @section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#Submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var mydata = JSON.stringify({
                  "ID": $('#ID').val(),
                  "text": $.trim($("#txt").val())
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/postdata',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                data: mydata,
                cache: false,

                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            });
        })

    </script>

}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually, it was resolved by adding the __RequestVerificationToken hidden field in the layout.  When the user logs in to ASP.NET MVC will automatically add this field to content however if a user is not logged in it is going to be missed so I explicitly added to _Layout page.